# ' Cleaning and building all projects is recommended'

Tags: android, build, prerequisites

> "The project cannot be built
>   until its prerequisite upomp_Res is built. Cleaning and building all
>   projects is recommended"

When I build an android project as usual, an error occurred as above.
Follow that infomation ,i cleaned my 'upomp_Res ' project and then cleaned my main project for  several times and the error still remains,and I reopend the project ,and even reopend my eclipse,it dosen't help,the error remains.

How to solve this?
Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even you cleared your 'Upomp_Res' Project , Eclipse will keep Launch configuration for that project. You need to Navigate Run->Run Configuration . Under Android Application right click on 'Upomp_Res' and click remove

Comment: It didn't work but when I switch my workspace and do it again,it worked,I do't know why...but thank you...